# How to output fixed length value from UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 function?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 to convert my date to ASCII value and then writing this value to a text file.

```
fl_rcrd :=
        '03'
     || RPAD (' ', 23)
    || RPAD(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 ('0' ||TO_CHAR (date_var, 'yyyymmdd') || 'C'),55)
     || code_var                
     || RPAD (' ', 79);
     
  UTL_FILE.PUTF (fl_handle, fl_rcrd || '\n');
```

Here the date_var should output at position 26 and total length with padding should be 55 and code_var should print at 81st position.
But date_var is coming at 84th position which means this line is `RPAD(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 ('0' ||TO_CHAR (date_var, 'yyyymmdd') || 'C'),55)`
is of total 58 length instead of 55.

[image: file_format]

Not understanding how to limit length of the output while using  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 function?

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284098/how-to-output-fixed-length-value-from-utl-raw-cast-to-varchar2-function

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "convert date to ASCII value"? Your use of `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` makes no sense to me. That function should be called on a `raw` input; your input is already `varchar2`, not `raw`, so you are relying on some implicit data type conversions. This has nothing to do with your specific question, but perhaps your specific question is irrelevant, because the whole process is fundamentally flawed. What is wrong with simply concatenating the result of `to_char(..., 'yyyymmdd')` in your string?